# Not able to login in Gtalk when using GPRS connection working perfectly when using WIFI connection

Tags: gmail, samsung-galaxy-s-2, google-talk

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S2. I am not able to log in to Gtalk or Gmail. The apps cannot load conversations when using a GPRS connection (error message: could not connect to server). But when I access Gmail through the browser using GPRS it works perfectly. Internet runs perfectly without any error.

Also these apps works perfectly when using a Wifi connection. Any suggestions on what the problem might be?

Comment: Which mobile network provider are you using and which APN?

Comment: Ask your cellular provider for "full" internet and not just WAP access. Most Indian carriers also route data via proxy servers. Ensure the correct settings are entered and the APN being used is for full access.

Answer (score 2):

Besides being an APN issue, [as pointed out by Aadi](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/16058/440), it could also be that your current mobile contract **does not allow some type of mobile communication** (like GTalk). You should contact your mobile carrier and ask him.

Answer (score 0):

It is an AP issue, call your operator and ask him to send the GPRS settings again. Once done, choose it and if it doesn't work, restart phone, it should work.

Comment: GPRS settings generally have APN values that matters. His web browser is working seemlessly.. So, there's no need of it..

Answer (score 0):

In the phone's settings: Communication -> cellular network -> access points

(The actual names/path may vary by language/type, but that should give you an idea)

I switched from WAP to INTERNET. The operator was providing it all along, just the phone was defaulting to WAP.